# Definitions of elements, nodes, branches, loop, mesh for a network with short circuit

Tags: short-circuit, terminology

**CONTEXT**

This question is intended to highlight the lack of precise definitions of basic circuit terminology that I have found.  For example, consider the following definition of branch.

> "A branch is a connection between nodes. A branch contains an element (resistor, capacitor, source, etc.). The number of branches in a circuit is the same as the number of elements. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdmhp.png)"

Notice that definition says connection between **nodes**, not **a node**. In the circuit below, R3 connects between only one node. So is there a branch through R3 or not?

Comments are welcome as are references to more precise definitions that deal with this sort of thing.

---

**QUESTIONS**

Given the circuit below:

Q.1. How many elements are there?

There are 4 elements.

Q.2. How many nodes are there?

There are 3 nodes.

Q.3. How many branches are there?

There are either 3, or 4 branches.

Q.4. How many loops are there?

There are either 1, 2, or 3 loops.

Q.5. How many meshes are there?

There are either 1, or 2 meshes.

[image: schematic diagram]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdmhp.png) https://spinningnumbers.org/a/circuit-terminology.html#branch

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is homework with no attempt at a solution.

Comment: In general, homework questions
enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we
only provide hints or Socratic questions and only when you have
demonstrated sufficient effort of your own, which you have not I am
afraid. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting
swamped by homework questions at the same time. Please revise your
question showing your work and findings so far, in considerable detail.
See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036)

Comment: replace the short circuit with a 0 Ohm resistor (R4) and you will be back in business

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the terminology isn't working very well when you have a short circuit across an element. However, I don't think the terms "branch" and "node" have a very formal, standardized definition. The textbook I use to teach does not say that the number of branches is equal to the number of nodes.

I think the root of this issue is that we usually just discard elements that are shorted before trying to analyze a circuit. So, by the time we get to the point of naming nodes and branches this conundrum has been quietly swept under the rug.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The only thing that doesn't sound "correct" is this part in your definition:

> A branch is a connection between nodes.

The rest of the sentence makes sense, though. Here is the definition of a branch/node from Fundamentals of Electric Circuits 5th Ed. (Alexander, Sadiku)

> A branch represents a single element such as a voltage source or a
>   resistor.
>
> A node is the point of connection between two or more branches.

The book also mentions that a branch can also represent any two-terminal element, which is (in a way) the same as saying "the number of branches in a circuit is the same as the number of elements."